# iphone sqlite3_column_text issue

Tags: iphone, string, utf-8, sqlite

I have a column in sqlite3 table. Column has values like

1 ½”

1 ¾”

2 ½” etc.
Column has VARCHAR datatype.

I am using this code.

```
pref_HoseDiameter = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
```

Now, when I am fetching these values from database, I am getting pref_HoseDiameter string values like this:

1 1/2"

1 3/4"

2 1/2"

How to fetch those values as they are in database or how to convert them that look like database values.

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `sqlite3_column_text16` to get the string as UTF-16, then create the string with `+stringWithCharacters:`.

```
const UInt16* text = sqlite3_column_text16(statement, column);
int text_len = // find the first 0x0000 in text;
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithCharacters:text length:text_len];
```

Comment: can you give me the exact syntax?